# What are some good online note annotation sites?

Tags: webapp-rec

What are some good online note annotation sites?

What I mean by note annotations is something like [Notable App](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2010/02/08/notable-app-a-collaboration-tool-that-lets-you-clip-annotate-and-share-feedback-on-websites-and-images/) which allows you to capture screenshots by URL or upload an image, make annotations and notes on that image and then allow you to share it with others.

Edit: I'm not looking for an app thats take down notes (I know many that are like this: [Springpad](http://springpadit.com/), UberNote, [Evernote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote), etc.). I'm looking for an app that helps me in getting feedback for a design by 'attaching sticky notes' to a site, much like how you might print out an image and then add notes to it through sticky notes.)

I'm currently using Notable App, but do others exist? Is there a better alternative? No specific criteria but there must be a free version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite out yet, but [Coda Notes Safari extension](http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/06/coda-notes-previe/) looks to be exactly what you are after.

[Free Range Feedback](http://www.freerangefeedback.com/) is also worth a look.

Comment: Cool, free range feedback looks neat

Comment: Its out :D http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/07/coda-notes-for-safari-now-available/

Answer (score 2):

[Crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com/) may be what you want. It lets you upload documents (PDFs, .doc's, etc) and images and annotate them, and also lets you annotate a "web page snapshot".

Their focus is on editing essays and the like, but it should be able to help you too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so this is all about taking a full page screenshot and paste some notes on it and share the resulting image? You could use http://aviary.com for this. You need to install a firefox extension (as the screen capturing on their website seems to be broken at the moment). The extension can save the screenshot directly into the aviary cloud where you can add notes and arrows and all. After that you can share the result between you and other aviary members.

Comment: There's an extension for Chrome too: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncgcgghbabbopfcpgcjpfffdgnbadegf

Answer (score 1):

Diigo may also be able to do what you want:

[Diigo](http://diigo.com)

Comment: How does Diigo do annotations >?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pixtick](http://www.pixtick.com). Screenshot capture, Image annotation, editing, publishing- all online.

> **Runs in almost everywhere:**
>
> It doesn't matter what the operating system is in your desktop or
>   laptop. Pixtick runs almost everywhere- whether it is Linux, Macintosh
>   or Windows. You just need a internet connection. Open www.pixtick.com
>   and start capturing, annotating and publishing. All from a browser
>   window. No plugins or download or installation.
>
> **Edit, annotate, compose:**
>
> Pixtick not only capture screenshot, its also having a powerful
>   annotation utility and some image editing capability. Working with
>   single or multiple images, resizing, rotating and cropping are some of
>   its main features. So no need to go anywhere for basic image editing.
>
> **Save, mail, upload, share, print:**
>
> Do whatever you want with your screenshots or edited images or
>   compositions. We have plenty of options for your publishing
>   requirement. Save them in your hard disk as JPEG or PNG or PDF format.
>   E-mail them directly from here. Upload them in our server and get the
>   image link. Share them in social network sites. Sharing in Facebook,
>   Twitter or Digg is just a one click job in pixtick.

For more information see [their blog](http://blog.pixtick.com/2011/04/first-look-pixtick-online-screenshot.html)

Comment: This is good, but you'd need to work on a "Undo" feature

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what everyone is saying you need to use the [Clip to Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php) Feature

> The Evernote Web Clipper let you save
>   interesting stuff you see on the web.
>   No more bookmarks, tabs, or open
>   windows. See something you like, clip
>   it and you'll have it forever.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can then share these with others using Evernote notebooks.

Answer (score -1):

As you've mentioned notable is a great app for this. You could try [Bounce](http://www.bounceapp.com/) though, it's by the same guys (Zurb) except it's way less complicated and really gets to the essence of the the problem (also, no limits, whoop!).

Comment: Bounce doesn't save it as an image file does it.

Answer (score -1):

[Notable](http://www.notableapp.com/) (as mentioned by OP) seems pretty full featured.

Comment: I know it's mentioned in the original question, but I thought it was worth adding individually to allow up-votes.

Answer (score -1):

FlexPaper has a plug-in which can be used to annotate pdfs/documents. Looks pretty good actually

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/annotations.htm

Answer (score -1):

Best free source to use is [Drawing](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/drawings/) in [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com). It can do everything that Notable can and for free.

You can import any image in Drawing. More than 1 user can comment, annotate, etc. You can share the folders or individual files.