# What note-taking apps can be used to assist in researching for a particular topic or task?

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good online note annotation sites?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/what-are-some-good-online-note-annotation-sites)

While Evernote, Springpad, etc are all *okay* for this purpose, they aren't **great** for **note taking where you have to take multiple notes all for the same task - e.g. when choosing a new tv**, you may want to go around and clip many different things all into one note.

What webapps are there that perform this task better, or how could I configure Evernote to be better at this (eg I could just use task-level tags, but what would be nice would be to set a note in the browser clipper and then all clips should go into this note unless I tell it otherwise/change the settings).

Comment: How about using a separate notebook named `TV Notebook`?

Comment: I think you need a better heading for this quesions, e.g. include "note taking"

Comment: @phwd, the problem with that is that if it is used for everything, then the amount of notebooks I would be left with would be unmanageable.

@Ian - good suggestion, and implemented.

Comment: I modified the title to try to make it shorter

Answer (score 0):

How about [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/)? While not completely a webapp, it doesn't require you to install it. You can create a page for each task and organise the notes however you like.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it out since the beta, but take a look at [WebNotes](http://www.webnotes.net/).  It is a toolbar for your browser that is for research notes, annotations, etc and you can organize the notes.  I'm not sure what has been added since.  Looks like they've added different pricing plans, but the basic, free one should be all you need it sounds like.

> **What is WebNotes?**
>
> WebNotes is an online productivity and collaboration tool spun out of MIT that is the first of its kind to combine the power of online annotation, organization and sharing tools into a single, easy to use offering. WebNotes is an essential tool for anyone conducting online research in order to gather market data, construct reports, or collaborate with colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Zotero Plugin for Mozilla! I use it all the time.

http://www.zotero.org/

Answer (score 0):

Browser based [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com/) seems like a good option for this, after having a look around.