# Website to store notes with an index cards like interface?

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good online note annotation sites?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/what-are-some-good-online-note-annotation-sites)

I'm looking for a website to store notes with an interface like http://webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/. I really like the possibility to move and reorder notes like index cards on my table. +1 if you could use some wiki/markdown like markup in the notes and if you are able to tag and search notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://taskless.appspot.com/ has the interface you are looking for, tagging, and stores all of your data in the cloud.

http://stickr.com/ is good for taking notes on webpages and seems to be more social-networking oriented.

If you are looking for a more study-oriented way to figuring things out, [lifehacker lists several index study card webapps](http://lifehacker.com/159157/create-customizable-online-flashcards-with-cueflash).