# Application for note taking designed specifically for students

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good online note annotation sites?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/what-are-some-good-online-note-annotation-sites)

Ideally, I'm envisioning something that allows you easily to take structured (indented lists / outline form) notes in class and organize them properly. If I were to build something myself I would include the ability to attach a .ppt or .pdf so one could view lecture slides alongside their own notes, but that is wishful thinking.

I've come across stu.dicio.us, which looked promising, but they appear to be down for the time being.

Any ideas, or should I make this a Christmas break project of mine?

Comment: Have you tried Evernote ?

Comment: I have yes; it's rich text editing is very glitchy (in particular lists, the most important part). I've recently discovered springpad which looks to be a fantastic alternative, but still not exactly a school-note taking app.

Comment: What about the online-version of onenote?

Answer (score 0):

Org-mode for Emacs may be a good choice. It has [plenty of ways to organize the document structure](http://orgmode.org/manual/Document-Structure.html#Document-Structure) and supports [links to files](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html#External-links) and [attachments](http://orgmode.org/manual/Attachments.html), although it can't show the file in Emacs, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Onenote, from Microsoft?  There's a free [online version](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/introduction-to-onenote-web-app-HA010378339.aspx).